# Interpret MarkDown tags in terminal console

Tags: html, c++, linux, c++11, terminal

I am working on a text editor that would be able to acccept both plaintext and Makrdown formats.

However I am not sure if terminal console would be able to display Markdown in desired format.

By that I mean if I used for example `<h1> Header </h1>` or `<b> bold </b>` I would wanted my console to display those texts as `<h1> header </h1>` and `<b> bold </b>`, however I am not sure if you can change font size in terminal console.

Is this possible?
Or do I have to use some kind of special library or even GUI?

Comment: ncurses library?

Comment: It totally depends on the actual terminal used what you need. As mentioned using `ncurses` is probably the best option to abstract this dependency out, there may be more. Maybe you'll find some inspiration from the open source console browsers listed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40350/what-is-the-best-text-mode-web-browser). Other than that your question is unfortunately _off topic_ either for being _too broad_, or asking for 4rd party resources at Stack Overflow.